# Issue in phpmyadmin update (to php 8.1)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

i was trying to update a phpmyadmin (PMA) db to match with php 8+ so i needed at least PMA to be 5.2
So i followed multiples help online without any successfull results.

This help was the last help i followed :
https://askubuntu.com/a/1204286

And this did this to my PMA :
[PMA login  CSS Broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVHcW.png)

When i'm connected, i can see that i'm in v5.2 : [Versions PMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uomKr.png)

List of subjects that i looked without any success :

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/947805/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-revisited
- https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/
- https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#upgrading-from-an-older-version

My server :
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-107-generic x86_64)
(no GUI)

Edit :
I found an error printed when i'm logged in :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJvnA.png)

I made a tmp file with 777 permission and the second error disappeared.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Still unsolved !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very easy. go into your phpMyAdmin directory and open the config.inc.php file with nano config.inc.php then change the blowfish secret with the new key, generate it here https://phpsolved.com/phpmyadmin-blowfish-secret-generator/ copy and paste.

Then scroll down until you see `$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';` and `$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';` below these two add the code `$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp/';` and save the config.

As last restart Nginx or Apache (I don't know which you have) and you're done. This should solve your problem. If that didn't work deinstall phpMyAdmin and install it new with this construction: https://codeshare.io/DZJd9E.

Comment: How do you do this on windows?